# PayPal not $_POSTing back data to return URL correctly from mobile devices

Tags: php, mobile, paypal

The checkout function on my client's site works by passing data to PayPal based on the following form:

```
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
  <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" />
  <input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="Confirm your payment" />
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="blah" />
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="blah" />
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="blah" />
  <input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="blah" />
  <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="products" />
  <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2" />
  <input type="hidden" name="return" value="blah" />
  <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="blah" />
  <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="blah" />
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="blah" />
  <input type="hidden" name="image_url" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="AU" />
  <input type="hidden" id="custom" name="custom" value="blah" />
  <input type="hidden" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:100%" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!"/>
```

When checkout is complete, and annoyingly after the customer presses 'Confirm your payment'; PayPal passes post information to 'return'.

This works in some cases. However, when a user pays via a mobile device such as an Android phone or an iPad, occasionally there is no data passed back to the 'return' URL in $_POST which causes a 'Payment Failed' email to be sent out to me with an empty $_POST variable.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I get the data to pass back correctly?

I have the items pulled from a database based on "custom", but my client is unhappy that all of the data (especially the address) is not sent conveniently in one email.

Answer (score 0):

I want to recommend not building your clients buttons that way. Any person who can edit html, can simply change the value of amount to $1 and if the merchant doesn't catch it, will ship a product that was only charged a buck.

You may want to complete this task with a api's instead of using $_post

Just seen it happen before.

Comment: There's a failsafe that won't process the order if the amount is changed. It's also served in the middle of a redirect, so they'd have to be fast LOL, but I see what you're saying. Could you please elaborate on using an API as an alternative? I had trouble setting up a listener to retrieve the information from PayPal, so I reverted to post

Comment: Check out https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ for classic api's or you could use rest api's